# How to force mySQL NOT to convert varchar to numeric in WHERE comparison

Tags: mysql, string, comparison, where-clause, numeric

When a table containing a column of type varchar contains data which could be converted to a numeric value, such as '100', mySQL (helpfully??) converts the WHERE string to a numeric value and returns a match for

```
WHERE column = '100'
WHERE column = '100.00'
WHERE column = '100abc'
WHERE column = '100areyoukiddingme'
```

I want to return only exact matches, but don't want to use the
`WHERE BINARY column =` as that would force a case-sensitive search when the value is not a numeric, which I don't want.  I also want to avoid using REGEX or LIKE as that would involve a table scan.

The search string is an ad-hoc value entered by the end-user, which may or may not be numeric, and the values in the table likewise.

How do I test for an exact match other than doing a double check on the column in PHP to check that the column does indeed match. Something like

```
WHERE column === '100abc'
```

would be nice.

### EDIT

This is not how mySQL behaves, it was my error in not checking the table I was testing with - the column was not defined as varchar as expected, but INT(11) therefore mySQL was casting all strings to integer correctly.

Comment: I'd recommend you run `explain select ... ` with different where clauses to see the effects: `where lower(column) = lower(<value provided>)`, `where hex(column) = hex(<value provided>)`, try regex and like route as well. It is entirely possible that although you may be reluctant to use one method over other first, the results may change your opinion.

Comment: I have done exactly that; REGEX and LIKE clauses do indeed cause a full table scan, as expected. Most of the time users will know exactly what they are looking for, so an exact match will save much time. The column has an index.  It is mySQL's behavior that is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
create table t7
(   id int auto_increment primary key,
    thing varchar(100) not null
);

insert t7(thing) values ('100'),('100kidding');

select * from t7 where thing='100';
+----+-------+
| id | thing |
+----+-------+
|  1 | 100   |
+----+-------+

select * from t7 where thing='100kidding';
+----+------------+
| id | thing      |
+----+------------+
|  2 | 100kidding |
+----+------------+

select * from t7 where thing=100;
+----+------------+
| id | thing      |
+----+------------+
|  1 | 100        |
|  2 | 100kidding |
+----+------------+
```

You know it is a string (meaning you know your schema has a `varchar`). So, pass a string regardless.

Comment: The point is that in your example, `select * from t7 where thing='100xyz'` will return id=1, thing='100'; which is not what I want. It should do an *exact* match and return an empty set, not try and be 'helpful' by assuming that by '100xyz' I'm really just looking for the number 100.

Comment: It doesn't. Look again unless i am missing something

Comment: Ah, I see from your example 2 that it did not return id=1. Thanks for your time. The mystery then deepens as to why it behaves as I describe on my table. Back to the drawing board.

Comment: If you make a sqlfiddle out of it we can check it out

Comment: My bad! the table I was testing with had the column defined as integer, not varchar, so mySQL was correctly casting my search string into int(11). Sometimes one can't see the wood for the trees. Thanks for your input Drew.